# PostgreSQL - Select Query between today's start time and end time

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, where-clause

I need to query database like - SELECT FROM table_name WHERE created_at = <--BETWEEN TODAY'S START AND END DATETIME-->

Sample data from created_at column is - 2020-09-28 17:02:14

Tried method is as follows but it didn't work,

```
SELECT FROM users WHERE created_at=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SELECT FROM users WHERE created_at=CURRENT_DATE;
```

Can any one help me with this query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
where created_at >= current_date 
  and created_at < current_date + interval '1 day'
```

This gives you all rows whose `created_at` belongs to the current day.